# How can I generate all combinations of 2 sets of unique numbers? How are those called?

Tags: algorithms, terminology, combinatorics, enumeration

I want to generate 2 sets from N elements.

- Sets must be unique in the combination of sets
- Numbers must not repeat across the 2 sets
- Sets can have any amount of numbers, but must not be empty
- Ordering doesn't matter

Examples for 3, 4 and 5

for 1 2 3

```
(1) (2 3)
(2) (1 3)
(3) (1 2)
```

for 1 2 3 4

```
(1) (2 3 4)
(2) (1 3 4)
(3) (1 2 4)
(4) (1 2 3)

(1 2) (3 4)
(1 3) (2 4)
(1 4) (2 3)
```

for 1 2 3 4 5

```
(1) (2 3 4 5)
(2) (1 3 4 5)
(3) (1 2 4 5)
(4) (1 2 3 5)
(5) (1 2 3 4)

(1 2) (3 4 5)
(1 3) (2 4 5)
(1 4) (2 3 5)
(1 5) (2 3 4)

(2 3) (1 4 5)
(2 4) (1 3 5)
(2 5) (1 3 4)

(3 4) (1 2 5)
(3 5) (1 2 4)

(4 5) (1 2 3)
```

I'm also curious to do the same for 3 sets, or maybe M sets, as long a M > N+1

for 1 2 3 4

```
(1) (2) (3 4)
(1) (2 3) (4)
(1) (2 4) (3)

(2) (1 3) (4)
(2) (1 4) (3)
(3) (1 4) (2)
```

I can use a bit of python with itertools.combinations and set() to maybe generate those, but when N or M is high it might becomes a bit difficult.

Comment: Do those sets have to cover all of the $N$ elements? If so, then this is usually called a [set partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set). There also is no efficient algorithm for this since there are $k^N$ partitions for partitioning all elements up to $N$ into $k$ sets.

Comment: Yes, they must cover all N elements. Thanks! I'm not really looking an efficient way to generate them, just if it has already been written since it doesn't seem trivial.

Comment: Ok so I guess this question is a duplicate